# c++ std::unordered_map singleton access violation error

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T> class singleton
{
public:
    static T* ms_singleton;

    singleton()
    {
        assert(!ms_singleton);
        long offset = (long)(T*)1 - (long)(singleton <T>*) (T*) 1;
        ms_singleton = (T*)((long)this + offset);
    }

    virtual ~singleton()
    {
        assert(ms_singleton);
        ms_singleton = 0;
    }

    static T& Instance()
    {
        assert(ms_singleton);
        return (*ms_singleton);
    }

    static T* instance_ptr()
    {
        return (ms_singleton);
    }
};

class Test
{
private:
   DWORD X;
}

typedef Test* LPTEST;

class TestManager : public singleton<TestManager>
{
public:
    TestManager();
    virtual ~TestManager();

    LPTEST  CreateTest(DWORD id);

protected:

private:
    std::unordered_map<DWORD, LPTEST> test_map;
};

LPTEST TestManager::CreateTest(DWORD id)
{
    LPTEST test = new Test;

    if (id)
    {
        test_map.insert(std::make_pair(id, test));
    }

    return (test);
}
```

I created a code similar to this.

when i run the below function.

LPTEST Tested = TestManager::Instance().CreateTest(61);

but "test_map.insert" gives an access violation error.

test_map.insert -> If I turn off the function it works fine.

all codes are normal. why am I having such a problem with std:map like codes.

I would be glad if you help.

Comment: `ms_singleton = (T*)((long)this + offset);` looks like undefined behavior to me.

Comment: What is that constructor supposed to do? That looks completely wrong

Comment: And this line is just strange `long offset = (long)(T*)1 - (long)(singleton <T>*) (T*) 1;`

Comment: Why not use simple `static` local variable? It's thread-safe.

Comment: yes, Example:
class test2{..}
void test2::start()
{
LPTEST Tested = TestManager::Instance().CreateTest(61);
}

Comment: You still have not explained what the constructor for `singleton` is supposed to do. To me it's completely wrong.

Comment: @drescherjm A code I wrote by researching.
I am not very knowledgeable.
How do you think I should write this code?

Comment: You should explain why you think you need any of that `offset` calculation in the constructor and what it is supposed to achieve. Why not just `ms_singleton = this;`?

Comment: If you want a singleton you probably want to look at: [http://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html](http://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html)

Comment: @UnholySheep as you said.
I used ms_singleton = (T*)(long)this;
but my problem is test_map.insert access violation problem.
and changing the singleton doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Remove those casts? Why are casting the pointer twice? That makes no sense at all. Don't add random casts into your code, especially when you apparently don't understand their purpose

Comment: Since the constructor of `singleton` is undefined behavior your whole program is broken. The cast can't work. You could use new to dynamically allocate a `T` object in your constructor but you are better of using a Meyers singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by changing the Singleton code as follows. I solved the problem.

```
template <typename T> class singleton
{
public:
    singleton() {}
    ~singleton() {}

    static T& Instance()
    {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }

    singleton(const singleton&) = delete;
    singleton& operator=(const singleton&) = delete;
};
```

@drescherjm , @UnholySheep
Thanks for your help.

Do you think there is a code in this code that will cause trouble later?
Could this code be better? How?

Comment: Right now, this is not a singleton. Your empty constructor is public, which means you can create an instance any time, you just can't copy it. Make it private.

Comment: @Aziuth I changed private singleton. but give the error C2248.

Comment: Means you create some object somewhere you don't want. In any case, don't just post the error code, post the full error, with the line that causes it.

Answer (score 1):

You code is way too complicated, dangerous and full of **undefined behavior**.

Here are some of the problems:

- The whole `offset` computation is a complete non sense!
- C style cast should be avoid. You should **always** use C++ cast like `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` perfectly understanding why you use such cast.
- You have a pointer to T but you never allocated any memory for such an object. As written, you mostly assume that memory is there.

In practice, with Meyer's singleton you rarely need to define such template.

Something like that is much simpler:

```
using TestMap = std::unordered_map<DWORD, Test>;

class TestManager
{
public:

    static TestMap &GetTestMap();

    Test *CreateTest(DWORD id);
};

// testmanager.cpp
TestMap &TestManager::GetTestMap()
{
    // Creation of the object is thread safe but if you want
    // to use it from multiple threads, you have to provide
    // your own synchronisation like mutex.
    static TestMap testMap;
    return testMap;
}

Test *TestManager::CreateTest(DWORD id)
{
    // allocate a pair and return a reference to value
    // if key already exist, return a reference to existing value.
    auto &mapValue = GetTestMap()[id];

    // as unique_ptr are stored in the map, 
    // memory managment can be simplified
    // could also use make_unique here
    mapValue.reset(new Test);

    // return a raw pointer as in your original code
    return mapValue.get();
}
```

Depending on the need and your level of understanding of C++, that code can be improved... As written, it is simple to understand once you know some basic C++ 11.